# JWT token authentication and autologin with ReactJS SPA and Django dj-rest-auth

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, cookies, jwt

I'm working on authentication system for ReactJS single page application and with backend
in Django using dj-rest-auth package.

The plan was to use JWT token for authentication, but there is one thing that causes my concern, which is CSRF protection.

Normally, a user logs in in React, meaning provides email/username + password
and the request to */login* endpoint and dj-rest-auth LoginView

```py
urlpatterns = [   
    ...
    path('api/login', LoginView.as_view()), # dj-rest-auth view
    ...
]
```

LoginView of dj-rest-auth package, when configured to use JWT tokens and disabled Session authentication as default (just JWT) automatically sets response cookies with jwt cookie and jwt refresh cookie (using Set-Cookie):

```py
set_jwt_cookies(response, self.access_token, self.refresh_token)
```

which results in setting Secure and httpOnly cookies saved in my browser cookies like that (names of cookies are predefined by me in Django settings):

[image]

Now - I'm expecting site to work in a way, that even after user closes the page and reopens it, my autologin feature in React would verify, whether user is logged in (or in other words
authenticated to view protected page) - so if the user is authenticated - React will
redirect to dashboard or some main authenticated page.

Autologin feature basically sends request to endpoint */autologin* using axios **withCredentials**:

```js
axios.post(url, body, {withCredentials: true});
```

The request, since I have already those 2 JWT tokens saved within browser cookies, will include those 2 cookies in request header and the request itself is handled by AutoLoginView

```py
urlpatterns = [   
    ...
    path('api/autologin', AutoLoginView.as_view()) # my view
    ...
]
```

```py
class AutoLoginView(GenericAPIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    throttle_scope = 'dj_rest_auth'

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return JsonResponse({
                'status': 'success',
                'data': {
                    'user': {
                        'email': self.request.user.email
                    },
                }
            })
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'data': 'Not authenticated'})
```

So, if jwt auth token is valid, the view will return success response, which is interpreted as autologin success and granted permission to view user dashboard (or any protected view). Is this the correct approach?

Should I also include in my authentication handling of CSRF protection attacks in that case? I assume, that if my frontend automatically tries to autologin or perform any authenticated action that is verified just by cookie tokens (which are sent with request by a browser) it might expose website to CSRF attack.

Since CSRF protection in Django is associated to SessionAuthentication, should I mix JWT auth with session authentication?

Another thing: If I enable Django session authentication - it includes csrf token with Set-Cookie as well.
So I have 3 cookies, not readable from client - but sent with every request - wouldn't that be a security issue? An attacker would be able to make any side-effect on server just by sending any requests with those cookies in header, which are included automatically.